# Web.config to ignore url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am developing a custom plug for Nop that uses the Chili publishing plugin.

Because the plugin is running on a difference domain to the chili publishing software I have had to configure url rewriting so I can control the chili plugin with JavaScript and not get "Access Denied"

But, the url rewriting means that the plugin has a url of, in this case...

http://localhost/Nop.Web/CHILI/..../editor.aspx?.......

And this means that Nop is jumping in and trying to serve up that page... resulting in a 404 error.

Is there some way to exclude this url from the Nop engine please?

Thanks

Comment: `routes.IgnoreRoute` http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx/ ?

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to do it the Chili recommended way. The documentation (the confluence wiki) contains a section regarding "Setting up cross domain scripting through Reverse Proxy" in IIS. Check it out: (Requires login)
http://docs.chili-publish.com/display/CPD4/Reverse+Proxy+on+IIS.

If you do it this way the request wont even end up in your site. The redirection will take place in IIS and you wont have to bother with it. Besides, it's always better to do it the recommended way.

We did it in our NopCommerce shop and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Why not provide a link to the documentation section you're referring to?